# In Angular 5, insert value in reactive forms array at specific index

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

Here, am using reactive forms array, i am unable to insert the **QuestionType** value into form array at specific index. Here is the JSON view of an array below:

```
{
  "SurveyName": "",
  "Questions": [
    {
      "QuestionName": "",
      "QuestionType": "",
      "AnswersList": [
        {
          "Answer": ""
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Here, is the inserting value in this way but, when am inserting like that key is removing from array here is the method below:

```
selectType(ID: number,event,index) {
    this.QuestionType = ID;
    this.SurveyForm.value.Questions[index].QuestionType = ID;
  }
```

It is the dynamic form to insert value at any index of an array so, please suggest me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With any `FormControl`, [you can call the `setValue` method](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#setValue) to update the current value.

If you're just trying to set a value in the form, and assuming the form control names are the same as the JSON Properties:

```
selectType(ID: number,event,index) {
    this.QuestionType = ID;
    this.SurveyForm.controls['Questions'].controls[index].controls['QuestionType'].setValue(ID);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for response, Here, got an error like: TypeError: Cannot read property 'controls' of undefined

Comment: Can you share your form initialization code or create a Plunk? My answer was based on the assumption that your form perfectly mirrored your JSON. The basic gist of this answer is that you want to locate the FormControl in your form that you want to update, and call setValue method to update the value. Without seeing your form structure, this is the best I can do.

Comment: Here is the fixed version. https://plnkr.co/edit/SWjYmV9d8LLDMc1V58iZ?p=preview 

I've updated the answer to match.

Comment: Could be either: `this.SurveyForm.get(\`Questions.${index}.QuestionType\`).setValue(ID);`